# In IBM BPM how to find component ID details

Tags: ibm-bpm

My client requirement is... instead of process portal using the URL they want to launch the process and access the task from their own portal.

For that CHS I exposed as URL and using that URL client portal they can able to launch the process but they cant able to process the task.

When I am framing the URL for processing the task. In that URL component ID also need. for that component ID where and how can we get that information i am not able to get in anywhere, Please anyone knows please provide me some information on that.

https://bpm.co.in/teamworks/fauxRedirect.lsw?zComponentId=3032.58aa9e8b-cafc-4264-91ce-8ac4671d7b27&zWorkflowState=2&zTaskId=t515780&zDbg=0&zComponentName=CoachFlow&applicationId=2&applicationInstanceId=guid%3Afa9c2963d7329bf6%3A-296c0055%3A173b30eee89%3A-8000

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Process entity by using this script:

```
tw.system.model.findProcessByName(tw.local.processName)
```

With the entity you can explore its attributes and get the information you want. In the script window use `ctrl + space` after this code to see available functions and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "fauxRedirect" link, can you please try the "process.lsw" one.

It would be something like

> https://<SERVER>:9443/teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=468&zResetContext=true&avoidBasicAuthChallenge=true

This will redirect you to the appropriate "fauxRedirect" link.